# Python websocket timeout when HTTP rejected, insead of returning immediately

Tags: python, websocket

Using the Python's WebSocket library version 9.1 [Docs](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/9.0/intro.html)/[GitHub](https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets/tree/9.1.x)

I connect to a websocket server (made in C++ heavily inspired by boost's flexi server example [Found here](https://github.com/boostorg/beast/blob/boost-1.68.0/example/advanced/server-flex/advanced_server_flex.cpp))

```py
 async with websockets.connect("ws://wrongUser:andPassword@localhost", max_size=2**28, subprotocols=["SomeApi"]) as ws:
   #Not relevant as we never get here
```

This connection eventually times out after 10 seconds, and gives me a `InvalidStatusCode('server rejected WebSocket connection: HTTP 403',)` exception. The exception is expected, as the username/password is invalid, but the fact that it takes 10 seconds to figure this out is not. 10 seconds is the default timeout, so when lowering the timeout I get the HTTP response when it times out.

Is it possible to make it report the HTTP error immediately after it has received it? so that I can have a longer timeout for slow connection but not need to wait forever when typing the wrong username and password

Comment: I don't know if this will work but you could try adding *open_timeout=None* and/or *close_timeout=None* as a connect parameters

Comment: @DarkKnight So I am running WebSocket 9.1, that does not have open/close_timeout (as I need to run python 3.6). However, I updated it to test, and setting `open_timeout` to `None` I observe the same as explained in the post (leaving it at default just gives me a timeout exception), except I time out faster if I set the `close_timeout` to a lower number.  Setting `close_timeout` to none times it out after about 15 seconds, no matter what I set the `timeout` argument to

Comment: In WebSocket 10.0 I also attached a logger, using the `logger` argument , and every single call (no matter the timeout) The logger immediately prints `WebSocketClientThread DEBUG: < HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden` after some few milliseconds. The whole log [here](https://i.imgur.com/GXkeCpt.png) for the 15s run with bot open/close timeout to `None`

Comment: Looks like it's neither a Websockets nor Python issue but it's to do with how you present your credentials to the server

Comment: @DarkKnight Nor certain what you are saying, if you refer to `ws://:@localhost:8000` I also did it with `ws://wrongUser:andPassword@localhost:8000` and get the same behaviour 
(Just a reminder I want the 403 error, but I want it immediately and not after like 15 seconds)

Comment: You may need to liaise with the author(s) of the Websockets module